# TypeScript function dynamic type inference

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
const randomFromArray = (array: unknown[]) => {
     return array[randomNumberFromRange(0, array.length - 1)];
};
```

My question is how can I dynamically type this input instead of using `unknown` or `any`. When I call this function, it understandably returns a type of `unknown` but I'd like for it to return the type that it was called with.

i.e. The returned type from `randomFromArray(['red', 'blue']),` would be `string` and the returned type from `randomFromArray([1, 2]),` would be `number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) parameter:

```
const randomFromArray = <T>(array: T[]): T => {
     return array[randomNumberFromRange(0, array.length - 1)];
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nr4l2W)